# MongoDB. How to project subdocuments in array if a key exists?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have this collection with an array of documents

```
        {
        "sub" : {
                "country" : "Netherlands",
                "sex" : "F",
                "mWeight" : 60.9,
                "birthdate" : ISODate("1961-05-26T00:00:00.000Z"),
                "age" : 38.5,
        },
        "process" : [ 
                {
                        "name" : "A",
                }, 
                {
                        "name" : "B",
                        "measurements" : {
                                "m0010" : 1725.39,
                                "m0020_mk" : 237.111,
                                "m0021_I" : 168.385,
                                "mvolume" : 61.5523
                        }
                }
            ]
    }
```

I want to find documents where "**process.measurements**" exists.
An project like this:

```
        "sub" : {
                "country" : "Netherlands",
                "sex" : "F",
                "mWeight" : 60.9,
                "birthdate" : ISODate("1961-05-26T00:00:00.000Z"),
                "age" : 38.5,
        },
        "B": {
                        "m0010" : 1725.39,
                        "m0020_mk" : 237.111,
                        "m0021_I" : 168.385,
                        "mvolume" : 61.5523
        }
    }
```

I want to eliminate the array and create subdocuments when "**measurements**" exists. Suggestions?

Comment: What if `process.measurements` doesn't exist? do you want to keep `process`? And I assume the key `"B"` is derived from `name: "B"`, right?

Comment: if measurement exists for both A and B, do you want separate document of A, and B, or both in one?

Answer (score 1):

You can use aggregation pipeline with [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/https://) and [$replaceRoots](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/https://) to achieve what you want.

The pipeline is divided in 5 stages:

1. unwind `process` array
2. get the elements where measurement exists
3. group and make process and array again (Step 1-3 is to remove unwanted elements from process array.
4. use `$arrayToObject` operator to convert `process` array to our desired object (Read more about $arrayToObject at [official MongoDB $arrayToObject docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/))
5. Use [$replaceRoots](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) with `$mergeObjects` to unwrap the object projected in step #4.

Try this :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$process"
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "process.measurements": {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      process: {
        $push: "$process"
      },
      sub: {
        $first: "$sub"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      sub: "$sub",
      measurements: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $map: {
            input: "$process",
            as: "el",
            in: {
              "k": "$$el.name",
              "v": "$$el.measurements"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          {
            "sub": "$sub"
          },
          "$measurements"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

you can play with the query at [Mongo PlayGround](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RKDcXsQH-2O)
Hope this helps you out!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you to take array elements of `process` that have the property `measurements` and use the property `name` as the key of the root elements.

In that can you can filter elements that has the property `process`, then convert them to objects with the property value of `name` as key. Then we merge those objects with the root object

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [ // 4. merge all objects with the root document
          "$$ROOT",
          {
            $arrayToObject: { // 3. convert objects to {[name]: measurements}
              $map: {
                input: {
                  $filter: { // 1. filter only elements that has measurements
                    input: "$process",
                    cond: "$$this.measurements"
                  }
                },
                in: { // 2. prepare data to convert to object {[name]: measurements}
                  k: "$$this.name",
                  v: "$$this.measurements"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: { process: false }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ad_3C6nDdnq)

Or a slightly shorter version for MongoDB v4.2 and later

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $replaceWith: {
      $mergeObjects: [
        "$$ROOT",
        {
          $arrayToObject: {
            $map: {
              input: {
                $filter: {
                  input: "$process",
                  cond: "$$this.measurements"
                }
              },
              in: ["$$this.name", "$$this.measurements"]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "process"
  }
])
```